# Jquery clone each not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i am trying to do is top convert a ddl to an unordered list and remove the first child element. This is working great when i have only 1 ddl to convert..

These are my codes:

```
var rep = jQuery(".input-box select")
      .clone()
      .find("option:first")
      .remove().end()
      .wrap("<div></div>")
      .parent().html()
      .replace(/select/g,"ul")
      .replace(/option/g,"li");

jQuery(".price-info").append(rep);
```

When i have multiple ddl\s to clone, nothing work..i have modified the above to this one:

```
var rep = jQuery(".input-box select");

rep.each(function(){
      jQuery(this)
      .clone()
      .find("option:first")
      .remove().end()
      .wrap("<div></div>")
      .parent().html()
      .replace(/select/g,"ul")
      .replace(/option/g,"li");
});

jQuery(".price-info").append(rep);
```

I am not sure if there is a problem with the each, or something else..

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone and replace the text the original jQuery object rep is not changed

```
var rep = jQuery(".input-box select");
rep.each(function () {
    var html = jQuery(this)
        .clone()
        .find("option:first")
        .remove().end()
        .wrap("<div></div>")
        .parent().html()
        .replace(/select/g, "ul")
        .replace(/option/g, "li");
    jQuery(".price-info").append(html);
});
```

Comment: logically your codes should be working fine..but in the second index of the clone there are no li's. just an empty UL. The first clone displays well

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: if i remove the (.find(option:first).remove().end()) it is okay. just maybe this bit needs to be re-written, what do you think?

Comment: @wasiim_dev can you share the html so that I can have a look at it

Comment: Actually, you are totally right..it was just that my second ddl contain only 1 option..thanks :)